# Draw a curve correctly using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting, plot

I have a couple of data `x0` and `y0` that corresponds to curve. It contains 8 points, for example : `K(x0(2),y0(2))`.

The problem is that when I plot `x0` and `y0` like this :

```
plot(x0,y0,'c*');
plot(x0,y0,'k');
```

I get the cyan point at a good place, but the curve is a mess. Check the screenshot:

[image]

Can I do some sort of `Sorting` ?

This question seems simple but I am a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the points define a convex polygon, you can simply use the `convhull`-function for this. `convhull` returns the indexes of the outermost points in `x0` and `y0`. For this question we exploit that they are arranged counter-clockwise around the hull, so you can plot them nicely after.

```
h = convhull(x0,y0);
plot(x0(h),y0(h),'k');
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

*Points used to generate the output:*

```
x0 = [1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1];
y0 = [2 3 0 2 1 3 0 1];
```

Comment: Very nice. +1... almost at 1K rep... and you've only been with us for a few days!  BTW, you should probably mention that the indices returned are guaranteed to be in counter-clockwise order with respect to the polygon.... that's how you're able to get the plot draw nicely.  The intersection shape that's in the OP's comment is already representative of the outermost points of the polygon pictured.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks :) Yes, today it's going to be 1k. But the coming days are not going to be that active since studies are calling for a recap before exams... Sure, I will mention the remark in my answer.

Comment: Ah I see!  I graduated about 2 years ago.... and I'm definitely never going back! lol.  Good luck with your exams!

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you! It's fully comprehensible xD

Comment: Thanks :) BTW, I've made a chat room for us MATLAB folks: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab - Come and visit whenever you're free~!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Mapping Toolbox, the function [`poly2ccw`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/poly2ccw.html) also performs the job for you.  Convex Hull is a more general purpose algorithm to handle any convex polygon.  If you already have the extremities of your shape, you can simply use `poly2ccw` return coordinates reordered that will allow you to draw the perimeter of the shape in counter-clockwise order.

Specifically, you would just do this:

```
[x1, y1] = poly2ccw(x0, y0);
```

`x1` and `y1` would contain the shuffled points of `x0` and `y0` so that they are now in counter-clockwise order.  You can then draw them via:

```
plot(x1, y1, 'k');
```